# I had a BTC wallet and had done some mining on my laptop a few years ago, now i can't find it

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery

So, this is the situation.... I had a BTC wallet and had done some mining on my laptop a few years ago (my now EX wife thought it was a waste of time....lol), now I can't find it and can't open GUIMiner
I have tried to find it to no avail.
How do I find it ?
If I download a new wallet will it automatically find the data file ?

Thanks

Comment: What wallet software were you using, what operating system are you on, and have you formatted your computer since then?

Comment: Does https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103688/5406 answer your question?